# Send image from clipboard to Photoshop

Tags: vb.net, clipboard, photoshop

Thanks for looking, any help would be appreciated:

I have hit a roadbolock in my application that im making that is basically lots of links and small functions to help my day run smoother. I want to be able to copy an image from the web and click a button and the image will be sent to Photoshops editor.

I have had success doing this with a drag and drop method, I can drag an image into my button and it will indeed open it in photoshop. However this only works with firefox for some reason and I use a range of different browsers. So if I can drag images, can I not get the image from the clipboard in a similar way and send that to photoshop?

I have tried the following:

```
if Clipboard.ContainsText then
  process.Start("C:\....Photoshop.exe", Clipboard.GetText) ' This just opens Photoshop
End if

if Clipboard.ContainsImage then
  process.Start("C:\....Photoshop.exe", Clipboard.GetImage) ' This alearts me that the image is not a string
End if
```

I also tried using a message box to show what the Drag_Drop was actually sending and it was just the link to the image. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Works perfectly, for anyone who want to know how exactly I did this I used this article support.microsoft.com/kb/818410 and used the functions IO.Path.GetTempPath to get the temp directory. I also used GetRandomFileName to get the files name. Happy coding, thanks Sani for the help.

Comment: You probably first need to save the image to a file and then feed Photoshop with that filename.

Comment: So I would get the image from the clipoard in visual basic, save it into a file and then open it. Then delete the temporary file? Sounds simple enough, thanks for the incredibly fast help :D